# Append dictionaries created using for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have create dictionary `d` inside the function `ic_strategy_2`. `ic_strategy_2` is iterated for each elements in list using `for` loop, which will create `3 dictionary`.

When below code is tested, only single `dictionary` is getting printed though I append it in `for` loop.

I want to append multiple `dictionary` created from `d` into one new dictionary as shown in expected output.

Thanks. Below is sample code.

Code-

```
# !pip install sorcery
from sorcery import dict_of
def ic_strategy_2(first,second,third,fourth):
    global d
    risk_reward_ratio = 10
    max_profit = 20
    nf_wed_range_pct = 30
    d = dict_of(risk_reward_ratio,max_profit ,nf_wed_range_pct)

lst = [[300,150,50,50],[200,300,50,50],[250,250,50,50]]
for item in lst:
    ic_strategy_2(*item)
    dicts = []
    dicts.append(d)

dicts
```

Output-

```
[{'max_profit': 20, 'nf_wed_range_pct': 30, 'risk_reward_ratio': 10}]
```

Expected Output-

```
[{'max_profit': 20, 'nf_wed_range_pct': 30, 'risk_reward_ratio': 10},{'max_profit': 20, 'nf_wed_range_pct': 30, 'risk_reward_ratio': 10},{'max_profit': 20, 'nf_wed_range_pct': 30, 'risk_reward_ratio': 10}]
```

Comment: `dicts = []` creates a new list each iteration of the loop. Try moving that line to before the `for`.

Comment: Are you purposefully not using your function inputs?

Comment: @ShlomiF, this was just sample code as stated in question, exact code is way different and very lengthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your description is that you'd like to create "one large dictionary", but your expected output example is a list of dictionaries. I'll go by the expected output example, assuming that's what you meant.
Also, you're reinitializing your dicts list in the loop.
You're also using hard-coded values for the dictionary, and not using your input. I'll assume this is a mistake; both in the code, and in the example-output...
And last but not least, a much simpler way to go around this would be to disregard the usage of `global` which isn't really required here, and just use the more standard `return`.
Putting it all together, I would suggest something like:

```
# !pip install sorcery
from sorcery import dict_of
def ic_strategy_2(first,second,third,fourth):  # You aren't using your outputs. Is this purposeful? "fourth" especially seems unused...
    risk_reward_ratio = first
    max_profit = second
    nf_wed_range_pct = third
    d = dict_of(risk_reward_ratio,max_profit ,nf_wed_range_pct)
    return d

lst = [[300,150,50,50],[200,300,50,50],[250,250,50,50]]
dicts = []
for item in lst:
    d = ic_strategy_2(*item)
    dicts.append(d)

print(dicts)
```

Comment: this was just sample code as stated in question, exact code is way different and  very lengthy.